# Condition on SCP policies for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Kindly ask you to help with conditions on SCP.
I need to have a policy that will block all actions on all S3 buckets but exclude particular buckets (like with prefix secret-bucket-*)

I didn't find any solution for bucket names only for the prefix of the object and tried with tags, but it also not working as expected:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Statement1",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/secret": true
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that help?

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"statement1",
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "NotAction":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets", 
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"  
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::secret-bucket-*"
         ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a policy that only allows the actions on the buckets with a certain prefix in the bucket name:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"statement1",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::secret-bucket-*"
         ]
       }
    ]
}
```

all other resources will be implicitly denied.